# Kubernetes CPU Usage Doesn't Match Load Test

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

#### Context

Hi guys, I am working on predictive horizontal pod autoscaler that is based on CPU usage. Now, I am testing to see if the model is able to scale the cluster according to the predicted CPU usage.

For testing, here is the stack that I use:

- App: [simple golang web server](https://github.com/yoelsusanto/tugas-akhir). The app receives a POST request then runs sha256 on a simple text. To simulate CPU load, this operation will be repeated as specified in the request.
- Monitoring: [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus)
- Load generator: [k6](https://github.com/k6io/k6)

For the test, I created a load pattern consisting of 1 minute of 5 virtual users then ramp up to 50 users for 1 minute and then repeat again.

#### Problem

I checked the CPU load on grafana to see if it matches the load pattern I have generated. However I found out that it doesn't really align with the number of user.

[image: Prometheus Workload Monitor & K6 Load Test Monitor]

Here is what I think is confusing from the CPU Usage graph:

- CPU load at 00.06.00 - 00.07.00 went up but doesn't reach the same peak as those in 00.11.00 - 00.11.30
- As the virtual user went down from 50 to 5 at 00.07, the CPU usage doesn't go down but it stagnated. I expected the CPU usage would drop drastically similar to the number of virtual users

#### Things I Tried

- Disabling open telemetry exporter: I suspected the exporter may use some CPU too. However I didn't notice significant difference after disabling the open telemetry exporter.
- SSH into the container, install HTOP and directly see CPU usage. The CPU usage show on HTOP is almost meaningless here. It just goes up and down, I don't see any pattern.

#### Question

- Is the CPU Usage pattern as expected?
- Is there anyway I can tweak the prometheus stack such that the gathered CPU usage will be similar to my expectation?

Thank you very much for reading this question. Please let me know if you need other information for better context.

#### Additional Details

- Prometheus CPU Usage Query:

  ```
  sum(
    node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_rate{cluster="$cluster", 
  namespace="$namespace"}
  * on(namespace,pod)
    group_left(workload, workload_type) 
  namespace_workload_pod:kube_pod_owner:relabel{cluster="$cluster", namespace="$namespace", 
  workload_type="$type"}
  ) by (workload, workload_type)
  ```
- Environment:

  - Kubernetes: GCP Kubernetes Engine v1.18.16-gke.502
  - Cluster: 2 node of n2d-high-cpu (4vCPU 4GB RAM)

Comment: I would question your choice of relying upon `kube-prometheus` as the real-time source of CPU usage. Might as well have a daemon-set with your probe-code to measure CPU load properly and send it directly to the k8s operator you are writing.

Comment: The Prometheus query you posted results in the cumulative CPU usage being measured, therefore it will average out any spikes. If you want instant CPU usage, use the rate function which calculates the per-second values.   For more information refer the link: https://www.robustperception.io/understanding-machine-cpu-usage